# Consider two consistent linear systems $Ax = b$ and $Ax = c$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two consistent linear systems $Ax = b$ and $Ax = c$. Is the system $Ax = b + c$ also consistent? Why?

I'm having trouble figuring this one out.

Comment: If $Ax=b$ is consistent, then there exists at least one $x$, i'll call it $x_b$ such that $Ax_b = b$.  If $Ax=c$ is consistent, then there exists at least one $x$, i'll call it $x_c$ such that $Ax_c=c$.  What can you tell me about $A(x_b+x_c)$?

Comment: $Ax_b + Ax_c = b+c$ ? And adding two consistents will also make it consistent?

Answer (score 2):

By assumption, there exist vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $A x_1 = b$ and $A x_2 = c$.  It follows that $A(x_1 + x_2) = A x_1 + A x_2 = b + c$.  Thus, the system $Ax = b + c$ is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to littleO's answer above (I'm still new to Math SE, and can't yet add comments):

If $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ is consistent, then $\mathbf{b}$ is in $\text{Col } A$. Similarly, because $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c}$ is consistent, $\mathbf{c}$ is also in $\text{Col } A$. And, because the vector space $\text{Col } A$ is closed under vector addition (and scalar multiplication), then $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c}$ is also consistent.